# How to Build Library Jar with Gradle

Tags: java, gradle

I followed this gradle tutorial:

https://guides.gradle.org/building-java-libraries/

with gradle 4.9 and for some reason in projects that reference the build jar can't see the Library class that should be created and be accessible once the project is built. I've changed nothing about the build settings and what not. Only run gradlew build from the command line to build the project.

I've tried finding the package path in my project, I've tried using eclipse to auto discover the import, it never finds it. (Note that the default method that the java-library type creates I've changed to *static* for my tests)

Am I missing something, I'm very new to Gradle and I'm trying to expose myself to it. But I'm familiar with just exporting a straight jar from the export window in Eclipse. So I can't quite determine what I'm doing wrong. 
Project Structure:

[image: Gradle project]

build.gradle file:

[image]

Comment: Can you please share your build.gradle and your project structure?

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] that reproduces the problem you are asking about.

Answer (score 2):

As per the [gradle tutorial](https://guides.gradle.org/building-java-libraries/) which you mentioned above, you first run the `gradle init` command which initializes the project by creating the project hierarchy for you as per the `type`. Your type is `java-library`.

Now run the `gradle build`command. Build is also a implicit task which when executed creates the artifact(jar) for you under `building-java-libraries\build\libs` directory.

Please note that I was not able to see the build directory in eclipse but I could see the same in my eclipse workspace.

Comment: It is not the eclipse portion that is the issue, I'm building from the command line, and trying to include the Jar in an eclipse project just to make sure that the build is working correctly and I can access the library inside.